# Some legend with meaning of V-RAP-NPM, API-3S etc

Tags: grammar, tools-of-biblical-studies, terminology

It is difficult for me to google the meaning of such short keywords like V-RAP-NPM or API-3S etc.

The following is in my bible lexicon:

> 1 Peter 1:8 ον(R-ASM) G3739 ουκ(PRT-N) G3756 ειδοτες G1492 G5761 ιδοντες G1492 G5631

Could anybody point me to a web page where I can find descriptions of these R-ASM, PRT-N, etc? Maybe it is obvious to native speakers, but I'm not one of them.

Comment: welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for the question.  Please remember to take the tour below.  To which lexicon are you using?  Each lexicon will usually have a glossary of such abbreviations.  However, they appear to be descriptions of the parts of speech and Strong's vocabulary numbers.

Comment: The lexicon you're using will surely provide its own glossary of abbreviations. Did you check?

Comment: Are you using E-Sword, perchance?

Comment: The Interlinear Bible on Bible Hub gives a good display and access to the information you want - https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_peter/1-8.htm If you just mouse over the bottom entry it will display parsing abbreviations for that word or click and see a complete list.

Comment: @user25930, first I saw these abbreviations in Davar4 application in lexicon downloaded from Davar4 pages. It is a quite simple application and it really seems that legend is not provided with the lexicon. I knew biblehub.com (recommended below) but I didn't notice the explanations provided in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this website can help you out:
https://studybible.info/mac

Answer (score 0):

The abbreviations can all be found on a standard web site for Biblical Greek such as

https://biblehub.com/1_peter/1-8.htm

This will tell you that:

- "ον(R-ASM) G3739" means the word is Strong's number G3739, it is a **R**elative pronoun - **A**ccusative **S**ingular **M**asculine.

There is a similar pattern for the others.  The hyperlinks will also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. This also useful web!